# Given p and q and (p ∧ q ⇒ r), use the Fitch system to prove r.

Tags: proof-writing

I am having trouble beginning to learn how to create proofs. I can understand the individual rules well enough, but putting them together seems to create a whole which is greater than the sum of its parts. I am not understanding why an Assumption of "p" followed by an AND INTRODUCTION of "q" and ending with an IMPLICATION ELIMINATION will not yield me a complete proof of "r." Can anyone offer assistance and possibly refer me to a tutorial?

[FitchProof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8koR.jpg)

Comment: What exactly is the problem with using And introduction to create a proof of $p \land q$ and the using Implication elimination?

Comment: I'm not sure. The course is given online as is the problem. I've attempted to prove "r" at least 6 different ways, but the program continues to say INCOMPLETE.

Comment: Is there a way you could show a picture of what you're doing?

Comment: Yeah I just found the exercise, and selecting $p$ and $q$ then clicking "And introduction" gives $p \land q$. If you select that and $(p \land q) \rightarrow  r$ and click "Implication elimination" you get the right answer.

Comment: The image is added now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're proving in that picture is $p \rightarrow r$ because you're unnecessarily assuming $p$ on line 4. That is under the assumption that $p$ is true you show that $r$ is true. But we already know $p$ and $q$ are true, so we need no assumptions. You can directly use them to prove $p \land q$ with And introduction. Then you can complete the proof using Implication elimination.

Edit: The reason you can't finish the proof in the subtree is because this would allow you to prove anything, after all you could assume it, then reiterate it and then say: "Look it's there I've proved it", that's why your proof must be completed in the main branch.

When we stop assuming something, we call it "discharging an assumption" which is what happens when we use Implication  introduction (Assume $a$, prove $b$, then discharge $a$ and you have a proof of $a \rightarrow b$). We can't say the proof is complete if we still have assumptions we haven't discharged.